# Why is there an error when trying to SELECT from a SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following code in C# to retrieve a table columns:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDataShape;Data Provider=SQLOLEDB;" +
  "Data Source=wmg-erp-db;Initial Catalog=DP;User ID=zh;Password=zhas"))
{
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SHAPE {SELECT FROM [DP].[dbo].[BT]} ", connection);

DataSet customers = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(customers, "Customers");
}
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Source Error:


Line 35: 
Line 36: DataSet customers = new DataSet();
Line 37: adapter.Fill(customers, "Customers");
Line 38: }
Line 39:    }


Source File: c:\Webserver\WEXEC\Booking\booking.aspx.cs    Line: 37

Stack Trace:


[OleDbException (0x80040e14): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.ProcessResults(OleDbHResult hr) +60
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.NextResult() +630
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +546
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +264
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +9
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +325
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +420
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +280
   booking.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Webserver\EXEC\Booking\booking.aspx.cs:37
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: You forget to specify your columns after your `SELECT` part. Something like `SHAPE * {SELECT FROM [DP].[dbo].[BT]}`

Comment: DUH!!! I totally overlooked that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed to mention the field/column name in your query statement. Either mention some specific column name (OR) `*` in your query

Line here

```
new OleDbDataAdapter("SHAPE {SELECT FROM [DP].[dbo].[BT]} "
```

should be

```
new OleDbDataAdapter("SHAPE {SELECT somecolumn FROM [DP].[dbo].[BT]} "
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify what you want to select.
A correct query would be
    `SELECT * FROM [DP].[dbo].[BT]`
That query will return all records.

Comment: Totally overlooked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM`, `*` missing.

Either specify column names, or `*` for all columns

[Refer](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp)